# Should I create a seperate controller for each input field in flutter forms?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am creating a basic form that may have two or more input fields. Should I create a controller for each or is there a way to use a single controller for all the input text fields.

Comment: yes, you should have one controller per input field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use one controller for each field. Take a look on this section of Flutter [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes) .